# Use equivalent of jQuery.get() in wix corvid

Tags: velo

I created a Chrome plug-in extension with the following code :

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: page_url
  success: function(responseText){ ...
```

In Wix corvid, I tried to use a fetch request by it is blocked due to CORS policy at the web server.

Aynone would know how to translate the equivalent of an ajax get request in Wix corvid ?

Thanks,

Hugues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use GET do this.

```
//myfile.jsw

export async function myBackendFnc() {
   const response = await fetch("https://api.website.com", {
      method: 'GET',
   });
   const json = await response.json();
   return json;
}
```

If the external web server is blocking this request then that is something you need to figure out with the external server on how to whitelist your ip.

You can use the GET from both your page or a server side code using a backend file.

Answer (score 0):

To make a successful fetch be sure to import the 'wix-fetch' API at the top of your code.

```
import {fetch} from 'wix-fetch';

// ...


export function getRequest() {
    fetch("https://someapi.com/api/someendpoint", { "method": "get" })
        .then((httpResponse) => {
            if (httpResponse.ok) {
                return httpResponse.json();
            } else {
                return Promise.reject("Fetch did not succeed");
            }
        })
        .then(json => console.log(json.someKey))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Check the API reference for more: https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/wix-fetch.html

You can also use use async await if you'd like.

You can create a web module in your backend and fetch from there. You also have the option of using 'wix-fetch' from the front-end as well.